# Nested JSON with query table from database

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nested-json

Below is the data from database table after query. Query is mentioned below in repository code.

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Year      | Name      | Count    |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 2020      | Motor     | 12       |
| 2020      | Nut       | 35       |
| 2020      | Bolt      | 47       |
| 2020      | Engine    | 78       |
| 2020      | Oil       | 125      |
| 2020      | Filter    | 5        |
| 2020      | AC        | 10       |
| 2021      | Motor     | 22       |
| 2021      | Nut       | 76       |
| 2021      | Bolt      | 2        |
| 2021      | Engine    | 5        |
| 2021      | Oil       | 6        |
| 2021      | Filter    | 6        |
| 2021      | AC        | 12       |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Below is the code i have tried:

**Code:**

```
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> retrieveData() {
        List<DataDTO> stud = dataRepository.findAllNameCounts();

        Map<String, Object> parent = new HashMap<>();
        stud.forEach(d -> {
            String r = d.getYear();
            Map<String, String> child = new HashMap<>();
            child.put("name", d.getName());
            child.put("count", d.getCount());

            if (parent.containsKey(r)) {
                List<Map<String, String>> children = (List<Map<String, String>>) parent.get(r);
                children.add(child);
            } else {
                List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<>();
                children.add(child);
                parent.put(r, children);
            }
        });

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(parent);
    }
```

**DataDTO:**

```
public interface DataDTO {

    public String getYear();

    public String getName();

    public String getCount();
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface DataDTO extends JpaRepository<DataSummary, String> {

    @Query(name = "SELECT YEAR(StartTime) as Year, Name, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM Data where  Name is not null group by Name, YEAR(StartTime)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DataDTO> findAllNameCounts();

}
```

**DataSummary:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Data")
public class DataSummary implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3269743987697633760L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String id;

    @Column(name = "StartTime")
    public LocalDateTime StartTime;

    @Column(name = "EndTime")
    public LocalDateTime EndTime;

    @Column(name = "Duration")
    public String Duration;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String Name;

    @Column(name = "Type")
    public String Type;

}
```

JSON currently i am getting from above code.

```
{
"2020": [
{
"name": "Motor",
"count": "12"
},
{
"name": "Nut",
"count": "35"
},
{
"name": "Bolt",
"count": "47"
},
{
"name": "Engine",
"count": "78"
},
{
"name": "Oil",
"count": "125"
},
{
"name": "Filter",
"count": "5"
},
{
"name": "AC",
"count": "10"
}
],
"2021": [
{
"name": "Motor",
"count": "22"
},
{
"name": "Nut",
"count": "76"
},
{
"name": "Bolt",
"count": "2"
},
{
"name": "Engine",
"count": "5"
},
{
"name": "Oil",
"count": "6"
},
{
"name": "Filter",
"count": "6"
},
{
"name": "AC",
"count": "12"
}
]
}
```

Expected JSON:

```
{
"primeData" :[
  {
    "year": 2021,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Motor",
        "count": 22
      },
      {
        "name": "Nut",
        "count": 76
      },
      {
        "name": "Bolt",
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Engine",
        "count": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "Oil",
        "count": 6
      },
      {
        "name": "Filter",
        "count": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "AC",
        "count": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": 2020,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Motor",
        "count": 12
      },
      {
        "name": "Nut",
        "count": 35
      },
      {
        "name": "Bolt",
        "count": 47
      },
      {
        "name": "Engine",
        "count": 78
      },
      {
        "name": "Oil",
        "count": 125
      },
      {
        "name": "Filter",
        "count": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "AC",
        "count": 10
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

From above single database table code how to create nested json with year type & count from single table. How to create a function that will give nested JSON response as Expected JSON